# No library found for processing.io error error when running Processing code in raspberrypi

Tags: raspberry-pi, processing

I am trying to run a `Sketch` program using `Processing 4.0`. The code is from `FreeNove` `raspberrypi` kit.

I am getting this error

```
No library found for processing.io
No library found for processing.io
No library found for processing.io
Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the sketchbook folder (see the Preferences window).
The package “processing.io” does not exist. You might be missing a library.
```

The code is snippt which seem to include `processing.io` is

```
/*****************************************************
 * Filename    : Sketch_09_1_1_Motor
 * Description : Control speed and direction of the motor
 * auther      : www.freenove.com
 * modification: 2016/08/22
 *****************************************************/
import processing.io.*;

int motorPin1 = 17;    //connect to the L293D
int motorPin2 = 27;
int enablePin = 22;
final int borderSize = 45;    //border size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, normally Processing ARM should ship with the [processing.io library](https://github.com/processing/processing4/tree/master/java/libraries/io).

If the install method the [Freenove manual](https://github.com/Freenove/Freenove_Ultimate_Starter_Kit_for_Raspberry_Pi/blob/master/Processing/Processing.pdf) provides (`curl https://processing.org/download/install-arm.sh | sudo sh`) doesn't work,
I recommend trying the official [Download page](https://processing.org/download) and selecting the Raspberry PI CPU architecture that fits (32 or 64 bit).

In the past I had success using the [Processing 3 Raspberry PI Image](https://github.com/processing/processing/releases/download/processing-0265-3.4/processing-3.4-linux-raspbian.zip) (which has Processing preinstalled): this could be a backup plan if you have spare microSD card (or don't mind flashing over you're existing one).
Even though it's Processing 3, hopefully the same `processing.io` features you need will be available.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the `curl` command but got an "unexpected redirection error". Then I downloaded the `tgz` file of `Processing 4.0` for `32 bit` `raspberrypi`. Ran its `install.sh` script and then tried the `.pde` program. But got the error.

Comment: Which version of Raspberry PI are you using ? Also, did you have any luck flashing the Processing 3 Raspberry PI image ?

Comment: pi-3. I didn't try flash. Don't prefer that route to be honest as it doesn't explain why I can't simply install and run `Processing`

Comment: pi-3 has a 64-bit ARM CPU, so the https://github.com/processing/processing4/releases/download/processing-1283-4.0b8/processing-4.0b8-linux-arm64.tgz should work in theory. (processing-4.0b8/modes/java/libraries/io/library/linux-arm64 is present). If for some reason it still doesn't pickup the processing.io library but the files are there, maybe some java classpaths are going awry.

Comment: I made it work by installing `processing 3.5.4` instead of `processing 4.0`.